# How get the server ip in socket progrmming?

Tags: qt, asp.net-core, sockets, qtquickcontrols2

I want to create a chat application like telegram in qt quick.

I had tested the application with IP `127.0.0.1` and I send a message to the server and the server will receive the message.

Now if I deploy the application, there will be many clients and any client is the server for another client(If I understood correctly the socket programming).

So when a user wants to send a message to another user, He should have the IP of another user(that is server), So How can I solve the problem of having IP of another user?

I have a rest API(asp.net core) for signup users. Should I save the last IP of each user when he make a request in my asp.net core web api? and with get list of contact I send the last IP too?

Or there is a another way in socket progrmming?

Comment: *...and any client is server for another clients...* That's not how Telegram works. All messages in Telegram go through Telegram's servers.

Comment: looks like you are talking about setting up p2p (peer-to-peer) connection which is not a trivial task